# Found a kind of worm in my rice bag, what should I do?

Tags: rice, safety

I poured some rice from a bag into a glass and noticed there was a worm(which looked like the rice) moving around in the rice.

How did it get there, would it have been packed in or would it have moved in since I opened the bag?
Can I remove the insect and still cook the rice, is it safe to eat?
Should I buy this brand anymore?

I was lucky enough to notice today since I poured it into a see through glass today but normally I've never been checking.  Assuming I've been eating this insect on previous occasions will it harm me?

Comment: Flour moth larvae or a relative, probably. Harmless (but still kind of yuck). And tour question is almost certainly a duplicate....

Comment: The _brand_ is not necessarily the problem, but the _store_ you bought it at could be (if it is a flour mouth larvae, they get into all sorts of grain products)

Answer (score 0):

In all grains there are insect eggs. It takes moisture for them to hatch. Or a insect could have laid eggs in the rice after opened. This includes flour even after milled. As insect eggs are very elastic. Can go threw milling into flour. Even inalators that shake flour to separate the yolk. In a few weeks the yolk in a insect egg reforms. So such will happen more than once in your lifetime. Does the whole bag have larva in it? If so feed it to the pigs or dog is best. But just one. That happens in life. So many insect eggs are allowed in all grain products. By Government standards. Chocolate is the worse or use to be. In parts per. million for this.